# Excecuting SSIS package deployed in Integration Service Catalog

Tags: ssis

I have edited my entire question, first my question was how to execute the SSIS Package, but now I have got the solution to execute it via SQL Server Agent job but when I am trying to execute the SQL Server Agent job, I am getting error , when I viewed in history then following message is shown

Job failed. Job was evoked by the user. Last step to run was step 1.

please note the table where I am inserting the data into database via SSIS package in SQL Express, is it SQL Express creating problem.

---------**Updated Error Message**-------------

The following error message is seen when I expand log file of SQL Server Agent job,

Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$SQL_Server_Evalu. Microsoft(R) SQL Server Execute Package utility Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64 bit copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All right reserved started: 16:11:39 Package Execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID:4, Execution Status:4.

Below is the screen shot how I execute the SQL Server Agent job,
[image]

------------**Updated error message**------------
Below is the screen shot of the error message that are given while execution of the deployed package.

[image]

Errors are as follows:

1) Data Flow Task Error: There were errors during task validation.

2) Data Flow Task Error: OLE DB Destination failed validation and return error code 0XC020801C.

3) Data Flow Task Error: One more component failed.

4) Data Flow Task Error: SSIS Error Code
   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER
   The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "RESHMAJADHAV\SQLEXPRESS.Adventureworks2012" failed with error code 0XC0202009.

5) Package Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLEDB error has occured. Error Code: 0X80004005. An OLE DB record is available. source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0X80004005 Description:"Login failed for user 'NTSERVICE\SQLAgGENT$SQL_SERVER_EVALU'.". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0X80004005 Description:"Cannot open Database" AdventureWorks2012"
requested by login. The login failed"

Is it because of the connection string

**"Data Source=RESHMAJADHAV\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"**

That I have defined in environmental variables in Integration Service Catalog I am unable to open the database..?

Any help will be greatly apprecaiated...

Comment: We need more details. You are running an SSIS package in the SSISDB catalog from a SQL Agent and it's failing. You *think* it is something to do with the Express instance. What is the **exact** error message? How are you calling the package in SQL Agent - either a screenshot or the command line tab should suffice

Comment: First things first: read the errors. You pasted the job error description, which only says that the job failed at the first step. In log file viewer, every log entry on job level can be expanded, and logs on step level can be seen, and that's what you need. Please edit your question and paste step error message.

Comment: Actually, with the new 2012 SSIS Project Deployment model, all you get in the Agent notes is that the package failed and it refers you to the reports in the SSISDB. Valid points though

Comment: @frikozoid ...Can you please explain him how I am going to check the error, whatever I have mentioned in the question in updated error message, I am not able to find solution to it.

Comment: @billinkc.. I am sorry but I didn't understood your's last comment.please can you explain it again.

Comment: @frikozoid.. Hi..I got to know the errors, I am updating in my question can you please look at it explain me the reason or solutions for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Data Source=RESHMAJADHAV\SQLEXPRESS;User ID=XXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Provider=SQLOLEDB;
```

for the destination connection. I think job is not getting the end user name and password.

It might help. I f not can you please post the exact error message. I am no able to see anything form the picture..
Thanks